# broken-like images after uploading images to WP library

Tags: php, wordpress, image, upload, woocommerce

I have a bizarre problem in my wordpress website. I talk to my host and they also couldn't help me out unfortunately. when I upload images to library for my products, some of them get broken. This is the screenshot :

http://www.pareshstore.com/wp-content/uploads/broken.jpg

The point is that they're not broken, but they seem to be broken. I can still insert them into product description or use as index picture BUT I can't add them to product gallery.

http://www.pareshstore.com/wp-content/uploads/sasasa.png

I should mention this broken-like images happened after migrating my website to the new host 7 months ago. But this problem (not able to add images to product gallary happened few days earlier, when I updated my WP and wooommerc)

Do you have any idea why 40-50% of my pictures after uploading get broken?

Answer (score 0):

Images you upload on Wordpress gets processed to produce difference sizes like thumbnail size, medium size, large size and the original size. Which means this take server resources. I would recommend to try re-installing Wordpress itself. DOn't forget to backup.

Comment: thank you @Roi . Another thing that I noticed is every thing in media list looks fine without any problem at all. 

In the list : pareshstore.com/wp-content/uploads/Capture.png 

product gallery :pareshstore.com/wp-content/uploads/Capture1.png

Comment: I think the broken images are the one produced by wordpress. the thumbs and other sizes.

Comment: So, you're suggesting to install a fresh WP. so you think after installing a new fresh WP, and importing my data, will this problem import also?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the uploaded file in wp uploads if it's appearing then you
   need to check your upload directory url [wp_upload_dir()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir).
2. If images are missing than disable your plugins one by one in order
   to check which plugin is making problem.

Comment: thanks to you both. Another thing that I noticed is every thing in media list looks fine without any problem at all. 
In the list :
http://www.pareshstore.com/wp-content/uploads/Capture.png

product gallery :http://www.pareshstore.com/wp-content/uploads/Capture1.png

Comment: I suggest you disable your plugins and revise the uploading process before creating a fresh installation of wordpress